# socket statistics (ss) program weird ipv6 listening socket address format

Tags: netstat, tcp-ip, ss

I have two services listening on TCP/IPv6 sockets, `ssh` and `mysql`. `ss` shows this:

```
$ ss -tl6
State     Recv-Q    Send-Q    Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port               
LISTEN    0         128       [::]:ssh              [::]:*                     
LISTEN    0         80        *:mysql               *:*
```

Why is the "Local Address" and "Peer Address" displayed differently for `ssh` and `mysql`? I.e. what if anything is the meaning behind "[::]" vs "*"? Note `netstat` shows no difference ("::" for both):

```
sudo netstat -natlp6
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address  Foreign Address  State      PID/Program name    
tcp6       0      0 :::22          :::*             LISTEN     26240/sshd          
tcp6       0      0 :::3306        :::*             LISTEN     23933/mysqld
```

---

**UPDATE** As @Amir pointed to in comments, there is actually a difference between the two services: `sshd` has two open sockets one for ipv4 only and one for ipv6, where as `mysqld` only has one ipv6 socket:

```
$ pgrep mysqld
23933
$ pgrep sshd
26240
$ sudo lsof -a -p 23933 -i
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  23933 mysql   27u  IPv6 6062236      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
$ sudo lsof -a -p 26240 -i
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    26240 root    3u  IPv4 6106855      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    26240 root    4u  IPv6 6106857      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

I disabled ipv4 in SSH config and `ss` still displays the two differently, but it maybe different type of ipv6 / ipv4 support as @Amir mentioned?

Comment: 1. Why is the "Local Address" and "Peer Address" displayed differently? They follow different conventions, not important. 2. What is the meaning behind "[::]" vs "*"? I am not sure, but possibly one of them is listening exclusively for IPv6, while the other also catches IPv4 implicitly through a process controlled by `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/bindv6only` on Linux (and similarly for other OSs)?